# Associate model instance to ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to Django. I have made two models like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    b_assigned = models.ManyToManyField(B, related_name='b_assigned')

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'a_table'


class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'b_table'
```

Serializers for respective classes are:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b_assigned = BSerializer(many=True, required=True)
    class Meta:
       model = A
       fields = ('id', 'title', 'b_assigned')
       read_only_fields = ('id',)

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = B
       fields = ('id', 'name')
       read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

I have already got few objects of `B` in the database.
Now for creating an object of `A`, I have to provide an array of objects of `B`.
How do I achieve this using Django REST Framework.

I know, I have to override `create` and `update` in `ASerializer`. But how to add array of `B` using their IDs to `A`. I don't want to create any new instance of `B` while creating `A`. Want to achieve this, using REST Framework only.

Clarification: I am posting IDs of `B` for creating/updating `A`

Comment: How about getting the IDs of Bs that you have in your database, and then adding them in the A's b_assigned in your create method? You don't need to create new instance of B.

Comment: here is an example to do so, but it creates new instances: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create new objects of `B`. As far as I can understand you problem, you are having problem in getting multiple `B` in your overridded `create` and `update`. There are two ways to achieve this, one is like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in), where you create a `query_set` and then iterate on the object. Example: `B.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 3, 4])`. 
Alternatively, you can iterate on the IDs in your method and then get those `B`s and then add them in your `A`'s `b_associate`.

I am expecting you have b_associate in your `POST` request.

```
ids = b_associate.split(',')
for id in ids:
    b_obj = B.objects.get(id=id)
    A.b_associate.add(b_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the same like this, thanks [Abhishek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520554/abhishek) for guiding me:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    a = A.objects.create(**validated_data)
    a.save()
    ids = self.initial_data['b_assigned'].split(',')
    bs = B.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
    for b in bs:
        a.b_assigned.add(b)
    return a
```